# Switching Enum Values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, hasura

i created an enun in sql

```
CREATE TYPE asset_type AS ENUM (
     'bat',
     'ball'
);
```

I want switch the value bat to ball

```
'ball'
'bat'
```

how can we switch enum values in sql

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TYPE asset_type RENAME VALUE 'bat' TO 'scratch';
ALTER TYPE asset_type RENAME VALUE 'ball' TO 'bat';
ALTER TYPE asset_type RENAME VALUE 'scratch' TO 'ball';
```

Not sure what the point is though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = 
  CASE
    WHEN column_name = 'bat' THEN 'ball'
    WHEN column_name = 'ball' THEN 'bat'
  END
```

probably with a condition, for example

```
WHERE player_name = 'Jack'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Actually what i want is i have `assets` table with a column of `user_type` of type `user-type`  enum  with two values **bat** and **ball** i want to switch 
`asset_type` value **ball** to **bat**

Answer (score 0):

Here we use an assets table and a foreign key so that only valid values from the assets table can be entered in the column.
The proposed update method will not work if there are more than 2 values for the class in assets, but could be modified to use numbers for the assets and then do something like `ID = CASE (ID = max ID) then ID = 1 ELSE ID + 1`

> ```
> create table assets(
>   class varchar(10),
>   vall varchar(10),
>   constraint pk_enums primary key (class,vall));
> insert into assets values
> ('enum1','bat'),
> ('enum1','ball');
> ```

> ```
> create table sample (
>   clas varchar(10),
>   val varchar(10),
>   foreign key (clas,val) references assets(class,vall)
>   );
> insert into sample values('enum1','bat');
> ```

> ```
> select * from sample;
> ```
>
> ```
> clas  | val
> :---- | :--
> enum1 | bat
> ```

> ```
> update sample set val = vall 
> from assets 
> where class = class 
>   and vall <> val;
> ```

> ```
> select * from sample;
> ```
>
> ```
> clas  | val 
> :---- | :---
> enum1 | ball
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1d5833cb20503a3557f47a97963f08a8)*